# Accessing socket.handshake inside express engine for authenticating handshake requests

Tags: node.js, angular, websocket, socket.io

I have a portal application which is built using Node.js and Angular and I am trying to implement real-time notification updates via Socket.io.

Below is the dependency info used in client and server:

**Server**

```
"express": "4.18.2"

"socket.io": "^4.7.4"
```

**Client**

```
"socket.io-client": "^4.7.4"
```

I have enabled both `websocket` and `polling` transport methods and I'm initiating connections only when user logs in to the portal.

However, when I try to pass `extraHeaders` header via `websocket`, it will not be available as mentioned in their documentation and this would only work for transport type `polling`. So, for the `websocket` to be authorized properly, we are can utilize `auth` property as an option for `io`

My concern is since `Socket.io` initially tries with `polling` and as a fallback it uses `websocket`, I'd like to pre-authroize both the transport types.

Here's how I'm creating instance of the `socket` in the client.

```
socket = io({
  extraHeaders: {
    Authorization: `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem('access_token')}` //To be used for polling
  },
  path: '/api/push-notify',
  transports: ['websocket', 'polling'],
  auth: {
    token: localStorage.getItem('access_token'), //To be used for websocket
  },
});
```

`extraHeaders` will be available in the `req.headers`, however `auth` would be available in `socket.handshake.auth`.

But the problem is, I'm not able to get the instance of the `socket` inside express engine middleware as it would follow, `(req, res, next)` structure and even if reference for `socket` is available in the `req.socket`, I'll always have undefined for the `auth` object and I feel this could be a different instance of the `socket` and not from `Socket.io`.

How could I make sure I get an instance of the socket even within express engine, to access the `auth` object via `handshake`?

Here's the entire piece of information from server and client.

**Server**

*websocket.service.ts*

```
import { Server } from "socket.io";
import { isValidSocketRequest } from "../utils/common.util";
import { logger } from "../utils/logger.util";
import {
  corsOptions,
  helmetConfig,
  cookieParserConfig,
  sessionConfig,
} from "../utils/app.config";
import http from "http";
import type { Server as HTTPSServer } from "https";
import type { Http2SecureServer, Http2Server } from "http2";
import * as core from "express-serve-static-core";

class Websocket extends Server {
  private static io: Websocket;
  constructor(
    httpServer: http.Server | HTTPSServer | Http2SecureServer | Http2Server
  ) {
    super(httpServer, {
      cors: corsOptions,
      path: "/socket-data",
      transports: ["websocket", "polling"],
    });
  }

  public static getInstance(
    httpServer?: http.Server | HTTPSServer | Http2SecureServer | Http2Server
  ): Websocket {
    logger.info(`Socket getInstance() - Invoked`);
    if (!Websocket.io) {
      logger.info(
        `Socket getInstance() - Instance not available. Creating new!`
      );
      Websocket.io = new Websocket(httpServer);
      Websocket.io.engine.use(sessionConfig);
      Websocket.io.engine.use(cookieParserConfig);
      Websocket.io.engine.use(helmetConfig);
      Websocket.io.engine.use(
        async (
          req: core.Request & { _query: { sid: string } },
          res: core.Response,
          next: core.NextFunction
        ) => {
          const isHandshake = req._query.sid === undefined;
          if (isHandshake) {
            if (await isValidSocketRequest(req)) {
              next();
            } else {
              next(new Error("Unauthorized User!"));
            }
          } else {
            next();
          }
        }
      );
    }
    logger.info(`Socket getInstance() - Ended`);
    return Websocket.io;
  }
}

export default Websocket;
```

*common.util.ts*

```
export async function isValidSocketRequest(req) {
  let token = req.headers?.authorization;
  if (token?.startsWith("Bearer")) {
    token = token.replace("Bearer ", "");
  }
  if (!token || token === "null") {
    return false;
  }
  let isValid = false;
  try {
    const { id } = jsonwebtoken.verify(
      token,
      process.env.JWT_SECRET
    ) as IJsonWebTokenPayload;
    const recordExisitsSql = `EXISTS(SELECT * FROM tbl_user WHERE eid="${id}")`;
    const recordExists = await db.query<Record<string, number>>(
      `SELECT ${recordExisitsSql}`
    );
    isValid = recordExists?.length && recordExists[0][recordExisitsSql];
  } catch (err) {
    logger.error(`JWT Error inside isValidSocketRequest() - ${err}`);
  }
  return isValid;
}
```

**Client**

*web-socket.service.ts*

```
import { Injectable, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { io } from 'socket.io-client';

@Injectable()
export class WebSocketService implements OnDestroy {
  socket = io({
    extraHeaders: {
      Authorization: `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem('access_token')}`,
    },
    path: '/api/socket-data',
    transports: ['websocket', 'polling'],
    auth: {
      token: localStorage.getItem('access_token'),
    },
  });
  constructor() {}
  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.closeConnection();
  }

  initNotificationSocket() {
    if (this.socket.disconnected) {
      this.socket.connect();
    }
    // client-side
    this.socket.on('connect', () => {
      console.log('connected!');
      const engine = this.socket.io.engine;

      engine.once('upgrade', () => {
        // called when the transport is upgraded (i.e. from HTTP long-polling to WebSocket)
        console.log(engine.transport.name); // in most cases, prints "websocket"
      });

      engine.on('packet', ({ type, data }) => {
        // called for each packet received
        console.log('Packet', type, data);
      });

      engine.on('packetCreate', ({ type, data }) => {
        // called for each packet sent
        console.log('packetCreate', type, data);
      });

      engine.on('drain', () => {
        // called when the write buffer is drained
        console.log('drain');
      });

      engine.on('close', (reason) => {
        // called when the underlying connection is closed
        console.log('close', reason);
      });
    });

    this.socket.on('notification', function (data) {
      console.log('notification', data);
    });

    this.socket.on('disconnect', () => {
      console.log('Disconnected', this.socket.id); // undefined
    });
  }

  closeConnection() {
    if (this.socket.connected) {
      this.socket.disconnect();
    }
  }
}
```

I'd be happy to share more information if required.